Axler: Necessary and sufficient conditions for operator to have upper triangular matrix
I'm working through Axler's proof of necessary and sufficient condition for an operator to have an upper-triangular matrix. I wanted to clarify my understanding of this section:

The equation in the red box says that $Tv_k \in \textrm{span}(u_1, \ldots, u_N, v_k)$. So with respect to this basis, $T$ is not just upper-triangular, but has the form

So the lower block is particularly simple. But I don't often see upper triangular matrices with this form. What are the conditions on $\textrm{range}(T - \lambda_m\mathbb{1})$ for this to be true?
